# How to label this plot?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code

```
 ParametricPlot[{{8 Cos[θ], 8 Sin[θ]}, 
                {7.7 Cos[θ],7.7 Sin[θ]}, 
                {7 Cos[θ], 7 Sin[θ]}, 
                {6.5 Cos[θ], 6.5 Sin[θ]},
                {6 Cos[θ], 6 Sin[θ]}},
               {θ, -5, 5}, 
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Red}, 
{Dashed, Blue}, {Dashed, Green}, {Dashed, Purple}, {Dashed, Black}}]
```

How to add label to each curve and text in the middle saying $a=0.3$ so the plot looks like

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{{8 Cos[θ], 
   8 Sin[θ]}, {7.7 Cos[θ], 
   7.7 Sin[θ]}, {7 Cos[θ], 
   7 Sin[θ]}, {6.5 Cos[θ], 
   6.5 Sin[θ]}, {6 Cos[θ], 
   6 Sin[θ]}}, {θ, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[Large]], 
   Directive[Blue, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
   Directive[Green, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
   Directive[Purple, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed, Thickness[Large]]}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Framed[Style["a=0.3", 20, Blue]], 
    Scaled[{0.6, 0.4}]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Red, Thickness[Large]], 
     Directive[Blue, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
     Directive[Green, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
     Directive[Purple, Dashed, Thickness[Large]], 
     Directive[Black, Dashed, Thickness[Large]]}, {"k=0.0", "k=0.1", 
     "k=0.2", "k=0.3", "k=0.4"}], {0.6, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add White box with black border around $a=0.3$?

Comment: @gbd see the edit

Answer (score 4):

Building on MMM's code I would use [`Dashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing.html) to dial in that part, and use [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) in [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html) to carry over those specifications.

```
ParametricPlot[{{8 Cos[θ], 8 Sin[θ]}, {7.7 Cos[θ], 
   7.7 Sin[θ]}, {7 Cos[θ], 7 Sin[θ]}, {6.5 Cos[θ], 
   6.5 Sin[θ]}, {6 Cos[θ], 6 Sin[θ]}},
 {θ, -Pi, Pi}, 
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
   Directive[Blue, Dashing[{.03, .02}], AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
   Directive[Green, Dashing[{.02, .01}], AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
   Directive[Purple, Dashing[{.012, .003}], AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
   Directive[Black, Dashing[{.014, .002}], AbsoluteThickness[3]]
  }, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Framed[Style["a=0.3", 20, Blue]], Scaled[{0.6, 0.4}]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
    LineLegend[Automatic, {"k=0.0", "k=0.1", "k=0.2", "k=0.3", "k=0.4"}],
    {0.61, 0.62}
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't knew that we can pass on a number to `AbsoluteThickness`.